# mostrar datos de usuario que inicio sesion mediante php y mysql

Tags: php, mysql

estoy tratando de ver los datos de un usuario al momento de loguearse, pero tengo un inconveniente este codigo es de login:

```
$usuario=$_POST['usuario'];
$pass=sha1($_POST['password']);


if (empty($usuario) || empty($pass)){
 header("Location: ../iniciodesesion.php");
 echo "la contraseña no coincide";
exit();

}


mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die("Error al conectar " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('proyecto2') or die ("Error al seleccionar la Base de datos: " . mysql_error());

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * from usuarios where usuario='" . $usuario . "'");


if($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    if($row['contrasena'] == $pass){
session_start();
$_SESSION['usuario'] = $row['usuario'];
$_SESSION['nombre']= $row['nombre'];
$_SESSION['nombre']=$row['apellidop'];
header("Location: ../inicio.php");
    }

guardo en session los datos
este codigo es para mostrarlo

session_start() ;


if(isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){


echo $_SESSION['usuario'];

echo $_SESSION['nombre'];
echo $_SESSION['apellidop'];



}
```

mi tabla se llama usuario
y los campos son:

```
id;
usuario;
nombre;
apellidop;
apellidom;
email;
password;
```

el inconveniente esta que me muestra el usuario, el nombre, pero apartir de apellidop me sale este error:

> Notice: Undefined index: apellidop in C:\xampp\htdocs\Proyecto2\verdatos.php on line 35

si alguien me pudiera señalar el error, o alguna otra forma de poder mostrarlo lo agradeceria

Answer (score 1):

El problema esta aqui `$_SESSION['nombre']=$row['apellidop'];`

Creo que lo correcto seria `$_SESSION['apellidop']=$row['apellidop'];`

Por que te daba ese error?
Porque en la linea 35 estas haciendo un echo de un valor que no existe (`echo $_SESSION['apellidop'];`)

Comment: session_start();
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $row['usuario'];
    $_SESSION['nombre']= $row['nombre'];
    $_SESSION['apellidop']=$row['apellidop']; agrege eso pero aun asi me sigue apareciendo el undefined index, solo me muestra el nombre pero apellido aun no, no se que a se debera

Comment: @AngelPantii Podrias actualizar la publicacion con el codigo actual? Asi se puede ver mas claro